# Should not have to disable eslint when using with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

So consider the following eslint file:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
            "jsx": true
        },
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "indent": [
            "error",
            2
        ],
        "linebreak-style": [
            "error",
            "unix"
        ],
        "quotes": [
            "error",
            "single"
        ],
        "semi": [
            "error",
            "always"
        ]
    }
}
```

It's pretty basic. I use the `eslint:recomended` extension and the [`react`](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react#list-of-supported-rules) plugin.

Now consider the following file:

```
import React from 'react'; // eslint-disable-line
import ReactDOM, { render } from 'react-dom'; // eslint-disable-line
import StartUp from './components/startup.js'; // eslint-disable-line

render(
  <StartUp />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Notice the disables. If I turned off elsint this whole system works fine, nothing fails to import, everything is found, the whole app loads fine.

But if I remove those disables I get the following:

```
  1:8  error  'React' is defined but never used     no-unused-vars
  2:8  error  'ReactDOM' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
  3:8  error  'StartUp' is defined but never used   no-unused-vars
```

This should not be happening. **What do I have to configure for it to understand that these are not "never used"?**

Comment: What are you using for your build system? I recently came up with a solution for this in our Webpack system.

Comment: @MikeC I am using Webpack 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using Webpack, you can circumvent ESLint entirely and just make sure that React and ReactDOM are available anywhere using the [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/). You can use it just like this in your Webpack config file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  // The rest of your config file...
  ...,
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      React: 'react',
      ReactDOM: 'react-dom'
    })
  ]
};
```

For the last one, make sure you've installed the [ESLint React plugin](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react)

```
npm install eslint-plugin-react --save-dev
```

Then include the plugin and make sure you enable the `jsx-uses-vars` rule.

```
{
  ...
  "plugins": ["react"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "react/jsx-uses-vars": ["error"]
  }
}
```

Then your code could be written like this:

```
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import StartUp from './components/startup.js';

render(
  <StartUp />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: Amazing :D Thank you :D

Comment: @TheWebs No worries :)

Answer (score -1):

I think you can add React and these others as a global in your `.eslintrc` files.

Comment: That will allow them to type `React` etc. in their code without ESLint yelling at them but it won't load the modules in to the bundle.

Comment: @MikeC That's not what the question was

Comment: It's most certainly part of it. If the solution breaks their build then it doesn't solve the problem. You might be right in the strictest sense but I'm more interested in solving the actual problem rather than going strictly against the wording of the question.

Answer (score -1):

There are rules that ship with eslint-plugin-react you can enable that will take care of that for you. Specifically, they are

https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-uses-react.md

https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-uses-vars.md

There is a recommended config for eslint-plugin-react, would be good to use that:
https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react#recommended